# Distribution resulting from exponentially distributed numbers divided by each other

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, lognormal-distribution

If I have two sets of exponentially distributed random numbers with mean parameters μ1 and μ2, what is the distribution of one set divided by the other?

I did this in matlab analtyically and the resulting distribution (histogram) 'looks' lognormal, seemingly regardless of the respective means. Numbers do not pass a KS/Lilliefors test for longnormality though.

Comment: Because the exponential is a particular example of a Gamma distribution, the answer is contained in the first two bullets at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Properties_and_related_distributions.